# Mongoose Cast to Array failed for value when creating instance of schema

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have defined a Mongose schema that has an array of another schema, as follows:

The **Property** schema/model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PropertySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    value: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
    },
    unit: {
        type: String
    },
});

export default mongoose.model('Property', PropertySchema);
```

The **Customer** schema/model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import { PropertySchema } from './Property';

const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    properties: {
        type: [PropertySchema]
    },
    deleted: {
        type: Boolean
    },
});

CustomerSchema.statics.createTestInstance = function(name, description, properties, callback) {

        let personnel = new this ({
            name: name,
            description: description,
            properties: properties,
            deleted: false
        });

        personnel.save(callback);
}

export default mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema);
```

**Generating test data:**

```
function getRandomProperty() {

    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    let type = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    let typeArray = [ 124, 2.345, 'Test', true];
    let unitArray = [ null, 'inches', 'certification', 'existance']

    let prop = {};

    prop.name = 'Random Property ' + rand;
    prop.description = 'Description Property ' + rand;
    prop.value = typeArray[type];
    prop.unit = unitArray[type];

    return prop;
}

function generateTestCustomer(name, description) {

    let props = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        props.push(getRandomProperty());

    CustomerModel.createTestInstance(name, description, props, function (err) {

        if (err)
            throw new Error('ERROR => Error creating test Customer: ' + err);

        console.log('LOG => Test Customer created: ' + name);
    });
}
```

And the result:

```
Error: ERROR => Error creating test Customer: ValidationError: properties: Cast to Array failed for value "[ { name: 'Random Property 408',
    description: 'Description Property 408',
    value: 124,
    unit: null },
  { name: 'Random Property 585',
    description: 'Description Property 585',
    value: 124,
    unit: null },
  { name: 'Random Property 277',
    description: 'Description Property 277',
    value: true,
    unit: 'existance' },
  { name: 'Random Property 709',
    description: 'Description Property 709',
    value: 2.345,
    unit: 'inches' },
  { name: 'Random Property 718',
    description: 'Description Property 718',
    value: 2.345,
    unit: 'inches' },
  { name: 'Random Property 836',
    description: 'Description Property 836',
    value: true,
    unit: 'existance' },
  { name: 'Random Property 944',
    description: 'Description Property 944',
    value: 2.345,
    unit: 'inches' },
  { name: 'Random Property 622',
    description: 'Description Property 622',
    value: true,
    unit: 'existance' },
  { name: 'Random Property 757',
    description: 'Description Property 757',
    value: 'Test',
    unit: 'certification' },
  { name: 'Random Property 508',
    description: 'Description Property 508',
    value: 124,
    unit: null } ]" at path "properties"
    at D:/DEV/v9/test/data/generatedata.js:72:10
    at D:\DEV\v9\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3800:16
    at D:\DEV\v9\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\model\applyHooks.js:155:17
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\DEV\v9\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\_babel-node.js:154:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

The generated array for Property seems to be fine, but I can´t find out why mongoose is throwing this error.

Comment: try defining schema field as just `properties: [propertySchema]`

Comment: Problem remains the same. No difference.

Comment: `let prop = new propertySchema()`

Answer (score 0):

You have imported your property schema to your customer model:

```
import { PropertySchema } from './Property';
```

...but you have not exported the property schema.

You have only exported the property model.